# Error: Object references an unsaved transient instance

Tags: nhibernate, castle-activerecord, castle, persistent

now I'm building a web application on asp-net using castle active record. When I was trying to save an entity with a has-many relation I got the error: "object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing. Type: SupBoardModel.Entities.Output, Entity: SupBoardModel.Entities.Output#0". Searching on the web I found the causes of this error and some of its solutions but no one worked for me. The relation already have a property set to Cascade = ManyRelationCascadeEnum.All, one of a common suggestion around the web so... What is wrong here??? There is a piece of code for more information and understanding:

```
 //In some part of my application
 State state = new State();

 //Set some fields
 //...
 state.Outputs = (List<Output>)Session["outputs"]; //Collection filled on a web form but not saved yet

 //Here is the error
 state.SaveAndFlush(); // Booom!!!!


//Part of a definition of Output(child entity)
[Serializable, ActiveRecord(Table = "SUPB_OUTPUTS")]
public class Output : ActiveRecordBase<Output>
{
    private int _id;

    /// <summary>
    /// Primary key
    /// </summary>
    [PrimaryKey(PrimaryKeyType.SeqHiLo, "OUTPUT_ID", SequenceName = "SEQ_OUTPUT_ID")]
    public int Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set { _id = value; }
    }

    private string _label;

    /// <summary>
    /// Output custom label
    /// </summary>
    [Property("OUTPUT_LABEL")]
    public string Label
    {
        get { return _label; }
        set { _label = value; }
    }

    private State _state;

    /// <summary>
    /// StateRef owner (An output is only available for one state)
    /// </summary>
    [BelongsTo("OUTPUT_ID_STATE", Lazy = FetchWhen.OnInvoke)]
    public State StateRef
    {
        get { return _state; }
        set { _state = value; }
    }
}


// Part of a definition of State(parent entity)
[Serializable, ActiveRecord(Table = "SUPB_STATES")]
public class State : ActiveRecordBase<State>
{
    private int _id;

    /// <summary>
    /// Primary key
    /// </summary>
    [PrimaryKey(PrimaryKeyType.SeqHiLo, "STATE_ID", SequenceName = "SEQ_STATE_ID")]
    public int Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set { _id = value; }
    }

    private string _name;

    /// <summary>
    /// StateRef name
    /// </summary>
    [Property("STATE_NAME")]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }

    private string _description;

    /// <summary>
    /// StateRef description
    /// </summary>
    [Property("STATE_DESC")]
    public string Description
    {
        get { return _description; }
        set { _description= value; }
    }

    private IList<Output> _outputs;

    /// <summary>
    /// State outputs (Columns to display data)
    /// </summary>
    [HasMany(typeof(Output), Table = "SUPB_OUTPUTS", ColumnKey = "OUTPUT_ID_STATE", Lazy = true, Cascade = ManyRelationCascadeEnum.All)]
    public IList<Output> Outputs
    {
        get { return _outputs; }
        set { _outputs = value; }
    }
}
```

This error is make me crazy. I hope that is a way to save the State without save each Output before. The cascade attribute has no change for me, all options (All, AllDeleteOrfan, SaveUpdate) give me the same result. This case is very common and is mentioned on http://docs.castleproject.org/%28X%281%29S%28znghcs55lveeljjvqg21vni4%29%29/Active%20Record.Getting%20Started.ashx but is a mystery for me. Can any body help me??

Thanks
Menrique

Comment: does it go away if you do
    `foreach (var output in (List<Output>)Session["outputs"])
    {
        state.Outputs.Add(output); output.Stateref = state;
    }`

Comment: Thanks Firo but it didn't work, I just got the same error. It look that is some thing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I put Cascade=CascadeEnum.All in the StateRef field of the Output, something like that:

```
/// <summary>
/// StateRef owner (An output is only available for one state)
/// </summary>
[BelongsTo("OUTPUT_ID_STATE", Lazy = FetchWhen.OnInvoke, Cascade=CascadeEnum.All)]
public State StateRef
{
    get { return _state; }
    set { _state = value; }
}
```

And It WORK!!! So is not enough to put Cascade = ManyRelationCascadeEnum.All only in the relation hasMany of the parent entity, is necesary in the child entity too.

Thanks
Menrique